# How to pass a token on an Azure Function response as a cookie with a redirect?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, function, single-sign-on

Considering the following code:

```
const { SAMLResponse } = qs.parse(context.req.body)
const { clientName } = context.req.params
try {
   const samlResponseFormatted = decodeURIComponent(
      SAMLResponse as string
   )

   logger.add(`SAML response formatted: ${samlResponseFormatted}`)

   const auth = await new SsoAuthenticate().getAuth(
      samlResponseFormatted,
      clientName
   )

   const expirationDate = new Date(Date.now())
   expirationDate.setHours(expirationDate.getHours() + 24)

   logger.add(`Token cookie expiration date set to: ${expirationDate}`)

   const headers = {
      Location: `${auth?.redirectUrl}`,
      "Set-Cookie": `token=${
         auth?.token
      }; Expires=${expirationDate.toUTCString()};`,
   }

   logger.add(
      `Answering the AuthSSO request with the following headers: ${JSON.stringify(
         headers
      )}`
   )

   context.res = {
      status: StatusCodes.MOVED_TEMPORARILY,
      headers,
   }
}
```

I can't see the cookie or the header after the redirect, and I need to pass the token to such redirected URL without passing the token as query parameters (Unsafe). I'm lost and probably this is not the right approach, but is it possible to send the token together with the redirect? If it's not, is there a better approach?

In [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/3551) they say that the better approach is to use cookies instead of just passing the token on the authorization header, but it's not working for me

EDIT: After researching a bit I've realized that the `Set-Cookie` is not working because of a cross-domain redirect (302). I need to think of an alternative way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

- To redirect you can use an express app on top of the azure function where all the traffic would be diverted to the express app. Basically the express app will be written in the index.js file of the `httptrigger` and will act like function.
- This is achieved using an `npm` package
   `azure-aws-serverless-express`
  code:

```
const  express = require('express');
const  azureFunctionHandler = require('azure-aws-serverless-express');
const  app = express();

app.get('/api/hello-world/', (req, res) =>
    {
    res.cookie('function','express');
    res.redirect('https://www.google.com/');
    res.send("Hello World");
    }

);

module.exports = azureFunctionHandler(app);
```

[image]

- This way now you can redirect to a different url .
- Also, you won't be able to set a cookie and redirect at the same time as the cookie you are setting will be related to a domain which itself is getting redirected.

Refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31910234/how-to-redirect-to-different-domain-with-a-cookie-in-express-js) by [jfriend00](https://stackoverflow.com/users/816620/jfriend00) for detailed explanation.

- The browser won't let you access the cookies as it is not of same domain
- So a compromise would be to pass whatever you want in the url itself as a variable

```
var token = "SAS_TOKEN"
res.redirect('https://www.google.com/${token}');
```

You can refer this [article](https://medium.com/nirman-tech-blog/sharing-cookies-between-different-domains-d3faec71e038) by Pradeep Moolmane on cross domain cookies, but it uses `XMLHttpRequest`